# Make selenium run through a list of websites faster

Tags: python, linux, selenium

I have a code with selenium that returns the title of a list of websites. This title is generated with Javascript (after the website is loaded, it goes from "Loading..." to the correct title in about half a second.) For this reason, the program loads a website, waits for the title to change, and then returns the changed title.

This is the code:

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from time import sleep
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
display = Display(visible=0, size(800,600))
display.start()
urlsFile = open ("urls.txt", "r")
urls = urlsFile.readLines()
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/usr/local/lib/geckodriver/geckodriver')
driver.set_page_load_timeout(60)
for url in urls:
        try:
           driver.get(url)
           sleep(0.8)
           print(driver.title)
        except TimeoutException as e:
           print("Timeout")
driver.quit()
```

The problem with this is that the list of URLs is very large, so for every website, I have to wait for it to load, and then the 0.8 seconds for the title to change and be printed.
Would there be a way to speed up the process? For example by loading many websites at a time, or by loading the next website during the 0.8 seconds that must be waited for the previous one to be updated with the title, so that this time isn't wasted.

Comment: You shouldn't need the `sleep()` since Selenium blocks until the page is loaded (not background processes but the basic HTML which should contain the page title). If some background process IS actually updating the title, you can use a `WebDriverWait` to wait for the title to change or not be "Loading..." but that's, at best, going to save you less than a second.

Comment: Your biggest performance increase will be to run your test in parallel. I don't know how to do this with python but with C# it's pretty straightforward using NUnit. I can run 8+ browsers at a time on a pretty basic PC. You should do some googling for a unittest library that has the framework to allow parallel execution and use it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what urls you are trying with but you can consider the below approach where you will get the title of the url, without loading the browser (this will make your tests faster)

```
import urllib
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.google.com"), "lxml")
print (soup.title.string)
```

Comment: If I do this, the titles printed will always be "Loading..." right? It won't wait for it to update. Nonetheless, I get a "module "object" has no attribute "request.""

Comment: In that case the other option is headless in selenium, that should make it little faster.

Comment: Still thinking if there is a way to run a test with different set of testdata parallel :-|

Comment: I used headless firefox before I changed it to that, and I got the impression it was a little slower.

Comment: @WeekSky if the website uses javascript, this will not work.